# overflow causes moving next block

Tags: html, css, sass

on the small screens next block moves down because pictures are too big and overflow prevents blocks from being displayed without space. Can i simulate collision in any way?

```
<div class="image">
    <img src="img/1.jpg" />
</div>
<div class="image">
    <img src="img/2.jpg" />
</div>

.image{
    width:100%;
    height:560px;
    overflow:hidden;
    display:flex;
    align-items:center;
    margin:0 auto 0;
    & > img{
        width:100%;
        height:auto;
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make your image height to 100% but then the aspect ratio will not be maintained.

```
.image{
width:100%;
height:560px;
overflow:hidden;
display:flex;
align-items:center;
margin:0 auto 0;
& > img{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
}
```

or you can change the height of .image to auto for lower screen sizes

```
@media (max-width: 980px) {
 .image{
   width:100%;
   height:auto;
   overflow:hidden;
   display:flex;
   align-items:center;
   margin:0 auto 0;
     & > img{
       width:100%;
       height:auto;
     }
   }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use media queries to sort this problem out, You can define your mobile view properties here for image

```
@media (min-width: 601px and max-width: (how ever many pixels you want)) {
  .image{
//Add properties here
}
}
```

Read more [Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)

Comment: you just don't understand my problem bro

Comment: no, just this pieces of code.
this blocks is situated like that as if they were without overflow, this black area has two hidden parts of pictures

Comment: Because you have given the fixed height of 560px inside your .image class

Answer (score 0):

Considering you are manually specifying a height for the images, they will attempt to occupy that height. However, considering they are roughly square, and they have a `width` attribute of `100%`, they will only expand in height until they reach the maximum width. As such, you end up with gaps between your images.

I'm not sure exactly you're trying to accomplish by specifying this fixed height, but you can't specify a height for an image, and at the same time restrict the width, without a gap. Simply removing the fixed height on `.image` solves the problem:

```css
body {
  max-width: 500px; /* Showcasing the problem */
}

.image {
  width: 100%;
  /*height: 560px;*/
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0 auto 0;
  border: 1px solid blue; /* Added to show the divide */
}

.image>img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="image">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/100" />
</div>
<div class="image">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/100" />
</div>
```

Hope this helps! :)